# Why Sin(30) = -0.9880316240928618 in java

Tags: java

I try to show the value of sin 30 in java (eclipse). But it's not a real value, My code :

```
public class sin30 {
public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("Sin 30 = "+Math.sin(30));

}}
```

and show :
[Showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXpXx.jpg)

should sin 30 is 0.5.
what's wrong with my code?

Comment: well you probably won't get exactly 0.5 even when using radians due to floating point arithmetic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before, you should transform it to radians like this:

```
  double radians = Math.toRadians(30);
  System.out.println("Sin 30 = "+Math.sin(radians));
```

Comment: thank you :) it's work very nice

Answer (score 10):

`Math.sin` expects a value in radians

```
System.out.println("Sin 30 = "+ Math.sin(Math.toRadians(30)));
```

Comment: thank you very much brother :)